# Dart 1.4.2 is not supporting on new chrome version

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

We have developed an application on the dart version 1.4.2 and has a pubspec.yaml following configuration

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  angular: 0.12.0
  angular_ui: ">=0.5.1 <0.6.0"
  logging: ">=0.9.1+1 <0.10.0"
  json_object: any
  js: 0.2.2
```

It is running fine on chrome version 77.0.3865.120, but when I upgrade the chrome version, so dart is not working or not supporting properly.It generates following error in the Web Developer Tool Console.

```
"NullError: Cannot call "call" on null↵↵STACKTRACE:↵TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined↵  
  at qEj.cv.er (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:46593:70)↵   
  at ecJ.$6 https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:6898:5)↵  
  at Wan.$1 (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:6887:5)↵  
  at dx.wh (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:59133:32)↵  
  at dx.h2 (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:59134:37)↵   
  at qo.ymM.Ix (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:58919:49)↵   
  at qo.ymM.y6 (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:58932:29)↵  
  at atm.$1 (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:5860:10)↵  
  at dart.bQ (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:17363:29)↵ 
  at Gv.Q.aN (https://localhost/xxxx/secure/secure.dart.js:2512:28)"
```

I am also putting before and after image that how it was on chrome version 77.0.3865.120 and How It was after updating to new chrome version.

Before
[image]

After Update to new chrome version

[image]

You can see that translation is not working any more on the webpage and It is appearing as it is, we have in the code.

Comment: Dart `1.4.2` is quite old now and not supported anymore (I guess), now the latest version is `2.9.3` we haven't you updated yet?

Comment: Yes, I saw in the documentation this version is depreciated and not supported anymore, but my question is that is it also not supported on the new version of chrome.